# Bloodhound - typeahead not showing suggestions that start with the typed search string

Tags: typeahead, bloodhound

I've been troubleshooting this for couple hours to no avail.

Basically, in the following code, I get the right results from the remote suggestions provider,

```
            var descuentos = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.nonword,
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.nonword,
            remote: {
                url: 'http://localhost:30045/Home/Suggest?q=%QUERY&type=name&fuzzy=false',
                wildcard: "%QUERY",
                filter: function (items) {
                    return $.map(items, function (item) {
                        return {
                            value: item.NombreComercio
                        };
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        $('#bloodhound .typeahead').typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 0
        },
        {
            name: 'descuentos',
            source: descuentos
        });

<body>
    <div id="bloodhound">
        <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Comercio Adherido...">
    </div>
</body>
```

But, when the suggestion STARTS WITH the search string, is not displayed... Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add `displayKey` to typeahead datasets parameter.

```
$('#bloodhound .typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 0
},{
  name: 'descuentos',
  displayKey: 'value',
  source: descuentos
});
```

Hope this helps.